# Rechart PieChart- How to convert to typescript?

Tags: typescript, react-hooks, react-typescript

I want to use a function like this rechart demo
https://codesandbox.io/s/pie-chart-with-customized-active-shape-y93si?file=/src/App.tsx

it's too long to show so I'm bringing here my demo to explain:

```
export const PieChartTab =()={
    const renderActiveShape = (props:any ) => 
    {
        const { cx, cy, payload, fill } = props;

        return (
            <g>
                <text x={cx} y={cy} dy={8} textAnchor="middle" fill={fill}>
                    {payload.name}
                </text>
            </g>
        )
    }

 return (
        <div>
            <PieChart width={230} height={230}>
                <Pie
                    activeShape={renderActiveShape}
                    data={dataAmHours}
                    cx={100}
                    cy={100}
                    blendStroke
                </Pie>
            </PieChart>
        </div>
    );
})
```

I want to use it in react typescript, but I don't know how to declare and get the props
in the right way.

Comment: All you need to do here is give the props the right type. Are you asking how you would write the type in TypeScript (syntax)? You might want to read [this page](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html) in the handbook to get you started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I got it.

First, I had to add the 'activeIndex' prop to the Pie component.
Then I declared the props.

```
export const PieChartTab =()={
    const renderActiveShape = (props: { cx: number, cy: number, fill: string}) => 
    {
        const { cx, cy, fill } = props;

        return (
            <g>
                <text x={cx} y={cy}  textAnchor="middle" fill={fill}>
                    {"data I want to show"}
                </text>
            </g>
        )
    }

 return (
        <div>
            <PieChart width={230} height={230}>
                <Pie
                    activeIndex={8}
                    activeShape={renderActiveShape}
                    data={dataAmHours}
                    cx={100}
                    cy={100}
                    fill={'#FFD669'}
                    blendStroke
                </Pie>
            </PieChart>
        </div>
    );
})
```

Note that the props I want to get for the renderActiveShape function I had to define first in the Pie component props.